# Optimizing queries in Django

Tags: mysql, django-models, mysql-python

I am creating a site using django. For testing I have created a database with 1 million rows each containing information(uploaders, orientation, description, and a handful of others) about images on my site. Each image has multiple tags which are stored in a tag relations database.
Tables are indexed.

Tag relation database
id

`tag_id` = foreign key to tag table

`Tag_relation` = foreign key to the image table(1 million rows)

Now I am providing a page where users can search images using tags and other parameters in the image row like uploader etc.

Now this is the query I am running for creating the search list.

```
SELECT * FROM photos_main_tb,photos_tag_relation 
WHERE photos_main_tb.id=photos_tag_relation.relation_id ORDER BY photos.rating LIMIT 0,10
```

Now I works allright giving me the images. But as the Limit becomes larger the time taken steadily increases and becomes several seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM photos_main_tb,photos_tag_relation 
WHERE photos_main_tb.id=photos_tag_relation.relation_id ORDER BY photos.rating LIMIT 500000,10
```

One optimization I could do was subquery and specifying a limit LIke

```
SELECT * FROM (photos_main_tb LIMIT 200,000,800000) ,photos_tag_relation 
WHERE photos_main_tb.id=photos_tag_relation.relation_id ORDER BY photos.rating LIMIT 
0,10
```

But this doesn't really solve my problem. I want to be able to list like this site: http://airteamimages.com/search.php. It doesn't slow down with many images. I am new to mysql. Forgive any blunders. I want to be able to load each page in the search in milliseconds, like the first query.

UPDATE:
  Like the first comment, I will stop selecting * instead only the id, which really speeded up things. But is there some other trick. And is this code worthy for production site?

Comment: Here's a great optimization step: stop selecting `*`.

Comment: There is no point in using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`. And the slowness probably comes form the big offsets. `LIMIT 500000, 10` means `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 500000`. Please add in what order you want the results ordered.

Comment: You talk about django and queries are wrote in sql but django query api.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance.. I want it to be ordered by rating or date whichever user select. Now the reason I gave the offset is lets say I am showing 10 images per page. So when user clicks on the next page or the last page option I have to do an offset to show the 10 images in say 500 th page.

Comment: Thanks ngk..without * it reduced the time many times.